# Autocomplete within a select element

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, sqlalchemy

I'm using a [json-editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor) to generate a widget for me using a schema that I pass from a sql database to the client side.

The widget contains several "select" elements...the options within these select elements can be expansive, I want to be able to have a input text field or somehow transform the select element to be able to have a user type what they want and have real-time search on the element. IE:

```
<select>
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        ...
</select>
```

I do have access to the JSON object to populate the selection so I can replace or store it internally where I can just create a html input element to have a "search" function. In a sense it would be like Google's search bar where it will actively query against the stored array and display them as you type.

Comment: Sounds like a wonderful idea.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First you want to render the taken JSON in an angularJS array like so:

```
$scope.myArray = angular.json(myData);
```

Then you can create a select box from this array:

```
<select>
   <option ng-repeat="element in myArray | filter:mySearchString">
      {{element}}
   </option>
</select>
```

And finally create a input to filter this array:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mySearchString">
```

This should work! let me know.